# What does the labelling of a conductor such as: 24 W 12 V mean? Does this mean the resistance of the wire or the current?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

[image]So I came across a question where a lamp was labelled 24 W and 12 V. 2 lamps that were identical and had this labelling were then put in series with a voltage supply of 12 V.

Obviously the individual voltage going through the lamps are 6V. But what I don't understand is that when there is this labelling of 24 W and 12 V, does this mean that the lamps will consume a current of 2A or does this mean the resistance will be 6 ohms (as P=IV and P=V^2/R)?

I personally don't think it will be trying to label the resistance of the lamp especially because resistance depends on the temperature of the wires...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "does this mean that the lamps will consume a current of 2A or does this mean the resistance will be 6 ohms". What makes you think it has to be one or the other?

Comment: Note: Most lamps are not ohmic resistors, and the current they draw is nonlinear in the voltage.

Comment: Here is the question above that makes me think it should be either the current or the resistance. The correct answer is B but do you think there might be an error in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24W is the power consumption of each lamp when connected across a 12V source.  Also note that when two of these lamps are connected in series across a 12V source, each lamp is experiencing a 6 volt DROP (it's not entirely correct to say that 6 V are going through each lamp).

With the given information, you can easily calculate the resistance of each lamp.  There are three general formulas that are used to calculate power consumption, and the one that applies here is:

$P=V^2/R$

This can be algebraically rearranged to calculate resistance.

$R=V^2/P$

Using the stated numbers, this gives a resistance of 6 ohms.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I checked the solution for this question, the correct answer is B which I will show you a photo of above; it says that it is incorrect to say that the resistance of the lamp is 6 ohms. I think this question might be an error though; please check the photo above.

Comment: I consider the problem to be ambiguous.  In the real world, the resistance of a lamp is a function of temperature.  For problems like you posted, several simplifying assumptions are normally made, and I would expect the problem statement to say that the resistance of each lamp is temperature dependent, but it didn't say so.  In other words, I would have chosen answer "A", and I am a retired physics teacher.

Comment: Okay thanks i understand a little! My question now is why would you choose 2 as an option because I assumed that the resistance is 6 ohms and the voltage through the resistors is 6V each. This means that the current in the circuit is 1A. So I don't understand why the current would be more than 1A?

Comment: @Phoooebe, oops!  I misread the problem statement, and thought that there was a 24V source on the lights.  Based on there being 1.0 A in the circuit, I don't see a correct answer listed.  And note - it is VERY easy to write a bad test question, which I know from experience trying to write my own test questions.  I consider this to be a bad test question, so don't get too "hung up" on it.

Comment: Okay I won't! Thanks for the help though; electrical circuits are the worst!

Comment: @Phoooebe, electrical circuits have their own logic.  I suggest you carefully read your text book, and try working example problems with the answers covered up.  When you can get to the point of having the same answer as the author, you will have learned the key concepts.  Also, the more problems you work, the better you'll get at it.  I have an engineering background, and my algebra work on my marker board was clean and right to the point.  I told students that my marker board work looked so smooth because I had filled up a couple of landfills with all of the problems I worked.